# Does BCP create the destination object?

Tags: sql-server, database, bcp

I apologize if I have a fundamental misunderstanding but basically I wanted to know if there is a way to go directly from ONLY .bcp files to creating a SQL Server database. I have not dealt with .bcp files before and have no format files or know anything about the schema of the database we are trying to re-create. Is there some sort of utility wihtin SQL server management studio that can do what I am asking or do I just not have enough resources to create a database out of this data. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: short answer - no. These files contain data only.

Comment: You MAY be able to do something. what is the format of the files? If fixed width... I'd tell whoever has asked you to do this... 'No'... for your own sanity. But if the files are delimited and have a header.. then the outlook is better. So, what is the format of the files? Do you have a header? are the fields delimited? Are the layouts wide (dozens or hundreds of columns?) or are they fairly simple (a dozen or less)?

Comment: Either way, BCP wont be the tool to use initially. You'll need to do some detective work (hopefully with help of headers and delimiters to start). From there create the architecture to hold the data and load with BCP or SSIS or whatever tool you prefer. But certainly, NO, bcp cannot inspect files and determine how to load them. You have to tell BCP how the data is formatted either through options or through use of a format file.

Comment: You might also want to try loading these files with the "Import Export Wizard". That will make some of the guessing/tinkering a little easier. Or if the files are small enough, open them with Excel (assuming the files are text, not native SQL data). Excel will make some guesses at loading the files.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

BCP only builk insert the data. So you need to have a blank database first to insert to with the bcp files.

You can use the bcp command line to run with those bcp files. But you need to know the order of the files to run if the db has FKs.